# Чтение из файла координат для использования их при построения рисунка

Tags: delphi

Есть текстовый файл,в котором записаны координаты в виде x;y. Необходимо по ним сделать рисунок в Image. Не могу придумать,как это сделать...

Пример значений:
0;0
15000;7500
40000;7500
40218;7510
40434;7537
40647;7586
40855;7650
41057;7735
41250;7835

Расположены в столбец

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Считай из файла первую точку, переместись в неё, считай вторую точку, нарисуй линию до неё, считай третью, нарисуй линию и т.д.

- **MoveTo**   Перемещает точку начала рисования линии в указанные координаты x и y    Canvas.MoveTo(0, 0);
- **LineTo**   Рисует линию начиная с текущей позиции (см. MoveTo) до указанных координат x и y. 
          Canvas.LineTo(15000, 7500);

  ```
  var F: TextFile;
  ```

  ---

  ```
  if OpenDialog.Execute then  
  begin  
  AssignFile(F, OpenDialog1.FileName);  
  Reset(F);  
  Write(F, 'Hello World');  
  CloseFile(F);  
  end;
  ```

Comment: спасибо,попробую

Comment: Если допустить,что файл открывается с opendialog?

Comment: @dead, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.